# deleting a node from a binary search tree in java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am making a boolean method that Deletes an element from the binary tree,
     Returns true if the element is deleted successfully
     , and Returns false if the element is not in the tree. The issue that I am having is that for some reason it is not deleting the node sometimes. I just want to know if I am doing anything wrong, thanks in advance.

here is my code:

```
public boolean delete(E e) {
    BSTDelete<E> d = new BSTDelete<E>();
    boolean deleted = d.delete(e, root);
    if (deleted)
        size -= 1;
    return deleted;
}

public class BSTDelete<E extends Comparable<E>> {

    public boolean delete(E e, TreeNode<E> root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (e == root.element) {
            if (root.right == null && root.left == null) {
                root = null;
            } else if (root.right == null) {
                root = root.left;
            } else if (root.left == null) {
                root = root.right;
            } else

                root.element = minValue(root.left);
            delete(root.element, root.left);
            // Delete the inorder successor

        } else if (e.compareTo(root.element) < 0) {
            delete(e, root.left);
        } else {
            delete(e, root.right);
        }
        return true;
    }

    E minValue(TreeNode<E> root) {
        E minv = root.element;
        while (root.right != null) {
            minv = root.right.element;
            root = root.right;
        }
        return minv;
    }

}
```

here is a test that keeps failing. The second assertEquals says that i.next() is "Beatrice" and not "Carl"

```
    BST <String>b = new BST<String>();
    b.insert("Arthur");
    b.insert("Beatrice");
    b.insert("Carl");
    b.insert("Dagmar");

    b.delete("Beatrice");
    Iterator <String> i = b.iterator();

    assertEquals(i.next(), "Arthur");
    assertEquals(i.next(), "Carl");
    assertEquals(i.next(), "Dagmar");

    }
```

and here is my BSTInorderIterator class:

```
 public class BSTInorderIterator<E extends Comparable<E>> implements 
 java.util.Iterator<E> {
 int current = 0;
 ArrayList<E>  list  = new ArrayList<E>();
 private TreeNode<E> root;


 public BSTInorderIterator(TreeNode<E> root) {
    list = new ArrayList<E>();
    inorder(root);
    }


/** Inorder traversal from the root */
public void inorder() {
    inorder(root);
}

/** Inorder traversal from a subtree */
public void inorder(TreeNode<E> root) {
    if (root.left != null)
        inorder(root.left);
    list.add(root.element);
    if (root.right != null)
        inorder(root.right);
}

@Override
/** More elements for traversing? */
public boolean hasNext() {


    return current < list.size();
}

@Override
/** Get the current element and move to the next */
public E next() {


    return list.get(current++);
}

@Override
/** Remove the current element */
public void remove() {
    // to do: make this work correctly
}
```

Comment: You have a method called `delete` outside of the class `BSTDelete` but also a `delete` method inside that class, which is a bit vague, which one are you calling?

Comment: the first one takes the element as a parameter and then sends the element and the root of the binary tree to the second delete method. the problem is with the second delete method

Comment: Adding a situation (code) in which this unexpected behaviour occurs would be handy to figure out what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The `delete` method inside the class `BSTDelete` is a recursive method, however you're never returning the recursive method calls. Therefore your `delete` method will only ever return `false` when you call it with a like `d.delete(e, root)` where `root` is `null`.

For example even though `delete(e, root.left)` might return `false` because `root.left` is `null` your original method call will return `true` since you don't return the result of `delete(e, root.left)`.

To fix this add `return` when you're calling the method recursively, this might only be a partial fix to your issue:

```
public boolean delete(E e, TreeNode<E> root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (e == root.element) {
        if (root.right == null && root.left == null) {
            root = null;
        } else if (root.right == null) {
            root = root.left;
        } else if (root.left == null) {
            root = root.right;
        } else

        root.element = minValue(root.left);
        return delete(root.element, root.left);
        // Delete the inorder successor

    } else if (e.compareTo(root.element) < 0) {
        return delete(e, root.left);
    } else {
        return delete(e, root.right);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: but the return true in the end is unreachable code right?

Comment: Yes it is indeed

Comment: so should I just delete it? because when I do it still doesn't delete the node

Comment: @Very123 In your code in the if statement of `e == root.element` I assume that's when you've found the element which you want to delete, I would have expected `return true` after that's been done and not another `delete` call

Comment: you mean the return delete (root.element, root.left); in the else statement?

Comment: @Very123 Yes that's what I would expect, however I do not have your entire code so cannot test it. What was the reason that you added `delete (root.element, root.left)` there?

Comment: @Very123 I mean the `delete (root.element, root.left)` inside the `if (e == root.element)` statement, not the `else if`.

Comment: because I want to replace the value of the node I want to delete by the value of the rightmost node in the left sub tree, and then delete the rightmost node

Comment: This code is not correct. It produces an error when trying to delete a leaf node. Also the code is badly indented.